# Пересечение прямой и составного коллайдера Unity 2D

Tags: unity3d

Дана прямая и составной коллайдер (Composite Collider).
Как мне найти точки пересечения прямой с подобным коллайдером?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Зеленое - точки пересечения, координаты которых мне нужно получить.
Красная - прямая или луч.
Чёрное - границы CompositCollider.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: [Physics2D.RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html)

Comment: Попробовал RaycastAll, он выдаёт первое только пересечение с Composite Collider, когда мне нужны все места пересечения.